# Reddcoin Paper Wallet

Tags: altcoin, paper-wallet, wallet-recovery, reddcoin

I am new with crypto and need your help!
I create a Reddcoin Paper Wallet with a generator from walletgenerator.net I already deposited an amount there! Now I have another reddcoin address where I want to transfer my amount from Paper Wallet! Can you help me with the transfer steps! I installed the wallet on my browser and it says he need to be synchronised with the net (it is about two years back: so it take a time to synchronise) I have the public address and the secret address! How can I open my old wallet to transfer to another address? Thank you for your support!